# Splitting up bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Borsuks conjecture and ball packings.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, graph-theory

I've got one (hopefully) easy and one a little more complex question on Borsuks conjecture.

In 1933 Karol Borsuk asked the following

> Can every bounded subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ be partitioned into $(d+1)$ sets, each of which has a smaller diameter than $E$?

Whilst new to this field of geometry I still have some open/unclear questions on this topic.

Early in game (to my knowledge even before any counter-example were known) Larman suggested investigating the problem when $E$ is a two-distance set. As a result of this suggestion many counter-examples emerged. Most recently the counter-example of [Bondarenko in Dimension 64](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2584) using strongly regular graphs which form a two distance set on a sphere.

As far as the 'easy' question goes it is:

How did Larmann come up with two-distance set? Why is it reasonable to think that those kind of sets contain many difficulties intrinsic to the general problem? What are those difficulties?

---

Another question emerges  from a result by Hao Chen on [Ball packings with high chromatic numbers from strongly regular graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02070v5).
Most likely it seems that this publication emerged from another MathOverflow question by Cantwell. Namely:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8232/chromatic-number-of-graphs-of-tangent-closed-balls/8488#8488 .

Just as Bondarenko, Chen uses strongly regular graphs to form a spherical two-distance set to construct a ball packing whose tangency graph is highly chromatic.

My question regards the part where Chen wants to link Borsuks conjecture to the ball packing problem. As written:

> The finite version of the Borsuk conjecture can be formulated as follows: the chromatic number of the unit-distance graph for a set of points with maximum distance $1$ is at most $d+1$. So the chromatic number problem for unit ball packings is the “opposite” of the Borsuk conjecture.

Why can Borsuk's conjecture be regarded as Chen names it. Somehow I don't get the connection between the "classic" conjecture by Borsuk and Chens version.

How is the coloring of tangency graphs of ball packings connected to Borsuk's conjecture? Why can the chromatic number problem for unit packings be regarded as the "opposite" of Borsuk conjecture? What opposite?

I will be thankful for every kind of advice or tip to my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment on the first question, but here's an explanation of the equivalency between the unit distance graph problem (Chen's version) and the original conjecture (Borsuk's version).

Let $S$ be a finite set of points of $\mathbb{R}^d$, and say it has diameter $\delta$. By scaling each point of $S$ by a factor of $\frac{1}{\delta}$, we can transform $S$ to a set of diameter exactly $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ that is, for the purposes of partitioning the set into subsets of lower diameter, exactly the same. So we assume without loss of generality that $S$ has diameter $1$.

Our set $S$ naturally corresponds to a unit distance graph $G = (S,E)$ in which two points $p$ and $q$ are adjacent if and only if they are distance $1$ apart, i.e., $p$ and $q$ are adjacent if and only if $d(p,q) = diam(S)$.

Here's where colorings of $G$ come in: a proper coloring of $G$ corresponds to a partition of $S$ into independent sets (each `color class' of vertices that get the same color is an independent set).
If a set $T\subseteq S$ is independent if and only if it has no edge between any of its vertices, if and only if any two vertices of $T$ are distance less than $1$ apart, if and only if $diam(T) < 1$.
Since the chromatic number of $G$ is the minimum number of independent sets into which $S$ can be partitioned, it is also the minimum number of sets of diameter less than $1$ into which $S$ can be partitioned, which is exactly the quantity we need for the Borsuk conjecture.

As for the `opposite' comment, see the full quote (I've bolded the important bits)

> A unit ball packing can be regarded as a set of points
> such that the **minimum distance** between pairs of points is at least $1$, then the tangency graph of
> the packing is the unit-distance graph for these points. The finite version of the Borsuk conjecture
> can be formulated as follows: the chromatic number of the unit-distance graph for a set of points
> with **maximum distance** $1$ is at most $d+1$. So the chromatic number problem for unit ball packings
> is the “opposite” of the Borsuk conjecture.

In particular, in the unit ball packing problem, points are adjacent in the graph when they are the *minimum* distance of $1$ apart, and in the Borsuk problem, they are adjacent when they are *maximum* distance of $1$ apart. In both problems, we want to find the chromatic number of the associated unit distance graph.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While the construction of the graph is clear for some finite set of points it isn't clear for me how this should work for all (possibly continuous) subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$. For example any finite/closed polyeder might contain infinitely many points with distance $1$. (Taking for example any sphere with diameter $1$ all points on the 'edge of the sphere' have an antipodal point with distance one. Thus resulting in infinitely many vertices in the unit-distance-graph).

Comment: @Felix, there's nothing wrong with having an infinite graph here. The chromatic number of the unit distance graph of the plane is a well studied open problem. However, it's worth noting that Chen does explicitly call this the *finite* version of the problem, because they're deliberately excluding having to deal with the types of sets you're talking about.

Comment: I have to come back to this.
`A unit ball packing can be regarded as a set of points such that the minimum distance between pairs of points is at least $1$, then the tangency graph of the packing is the unit-distance graph for these points. `
In a **unit** ball packing two tangent balls (represented by points in the mid of the ball) always have exactly distance $2$, and could never have distance $1$. Thus the **unit**-distance graph would be empty (and different to the tangency graph). Sure one could scale the balls to _half-unit balls_ but this isn't what we wanted.

Comment: Scaling the radius of the balls to $\frac{1}{2}$ gives us exactly what we want, because then the unit distance graph is the same as the tangency graph. We could choose our 'unit' balls to all be whatever radius $r$ we like, so long as it's the same for all balls, and geometrically it is the exact same as the unit distance problem.